# Time complexity of this recurrence

Tags: algorithm, time

Is  T (n) = T (n/2) + 2^n possible on master method?﻿

How to measure the time complexity of this recurrence.Thanks

Comment: whats the base case?

Comment: @Mitchel0022 it doesn't matter, since only the complexity is desired.

Answer (score 0):

Well, do a few expansion:

```
T(n) = 2^n + T(n/2)
     = 2^n + 2^(n/2) + T(n/4)
     = 2^n + 2^(n/2) + 2^(n/4) + T(n/8)
```

...etc.

Obviously, the complexity is at least **Ω(2^n)**, since there's a **2^n** in the expansion.

Furthermore, the terms added in each expansion get small really fast.  You probably already know that:

```
2^n + 2^(n-1) + 2^(n-2)...  = O(2^n)
```

You have:

```
2^n + 2^(n/2) + 2^(n/4)...
```

and those terms, except for the first, are all *smaller* until **n<2** (around a base case), so your sequence is in **O(2^n)** as well, i.e., the lower bound is tight and the recurrence is in **Θ(2^n)**